# Problem resigning UISearchBar's firstResponder status

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar, exc-bad-access, first-responder

I've got a `UISearchBar` on my `UITableView` and a method `-finishSearching` which looks like this:

```
- (void)finishSearching {
    [overlayViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    if ([sb isFirstResponder])
        [sb resignFirstResponder];
    myTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

This method gets called everytime I want to stop searching. Be it using the cancel or the search button or just tapping on the `UITableView`. The problem is that I always get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when it comes to `[sb resignFirstResponder];` and I have no idea why. My goal is to implement a behavior like in Address Book where you can tap the searchBar which makes it stick to the top and put that grey overlay over the `UITableView`.

Any suggestions on that one?

Best
–f

Comment: Try changing the order (in particular, if sb is a subview of overlayViewController.view, then you are resigning first responder after it's been removed from the view hierarchy, which at least in previous versions was a Bad Thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that by `removeFromSuperview` the `sb` will not be released a little too early? Try resigning first and then removing the view from the superview.

Comment: Uhm, I'm not removing `sb` from it's superview here. It's the `overlayViewController`'s view property.

Comment: I know. But I wonder who is retaining the `sb`. If you're positive that your object is retaining it, look for another solution.

Comment: Ok, I found the bug. I was producing an infinite loop when resigning first responder because I called my `-finishSearching` method from within the method that gets called when the `searchBar` wants to resign the `firstResponder` status. Thanks anyways!